# Integral tie-back in AtlasPlugin.cpp seems wrong - causes control glitches

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The code at roughly line 1066 in AtlasPlugin.cpp appears to be wrong.  Specifically, it generally will invert the k_i_q_i term on a step change and saturate in the opposite of the commanded direction.

If a negative step is applied that results in a clamped force then the code can result in a k_i_q_i that is clamped at the positive limit.  This results in a joint excursion in the opposite of the desired direction.

This is not a desired behaviour.  I would recommend simply removing the problematic code.

```
// lock integral term to provide continuous control as system moves
// out of staturation
this->errorTerms[i].k_i_q_i = math::clamp(
        this->errorTerms[i].k_i_q_i + (forceClamped - forceUnclamped),
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2309/integral-tie-back-in-atlasplugin.cpp-seems-wrong---causes-control-glitches/) by [GoRobotGo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/123/gorobotgo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

please continue discussion on [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/182/integral-tie-back-in-atlasplugincpp-seems).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0